# Python: Calculating VAT amount on different input prices

Tags: python

> Hey, I am having trouble with calculating VAT on different prices.  If
>   priceR250 then the VAT rate=7.5%. When I run
>   my code I receive None for the VAT amount.

```
item_price1 = int(input("Enter the item price: R "))

def vat_calc(price):
    if price<100:
        vat_amount=price*0.15
    elif price>101 and price<249:
        vat_amount=price*0.10
    else:
        vat_amount=price*0.075
print("VAT amount: R", vat_calc(item_price1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never return anything, add a `return` statement at the end of your function:

```
item_price1 = int(input("Enter the item price: R "))

def vat_calc(price):
    if price<100:
        vat_amount=price*0.15
    elif price>101 and price<249:
        vat_amount=price*0.10
    else:
        vat_amount=price*0.075
    return vat_amount

print("VAT amount: R", vat_calc(item_price1))
```

Comment: @Anonymous No problem. Please click the check mark next to my answer to let others now this worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the vat amount, add `return vat_amount` to the end of your function.